# Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 happening with valid JSON in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jsonschema

I have a file called `HeartbeatResponse_v1p0.json` whose contents are as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "$id": "urn:OCPP:Cp:2:2018:4:HeartbeatResponse",
  "comment": "OCPP 2.0 - v1p0",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "properties": {
    "currentTime": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "currentTime"
  ]
}
```

Now in `index.js`, I am trying to `JSON.parse` it.

```
const fs = require('fs')
var schema = fs.readFileSync('./HeartbeatResponse_v1p0.json')
console.log(JSON.parse(schema.toString()))
```

But I get the following error:

```
undefined:1
{
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    .........
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Please help me.

Comment: This code works fine - the json is valid and it parses the contents. There must be some other issue in your code or the json you supplied is not the same as in the file you are reading. I copy-pasted the json contents so there might still be a difference with the file *you* are using.

Comment: To note, in node you can use `require()` to load JSON files just like a JavaScript file:  `let schema = require('./HeartbeatResponse_v1p0.json')`

Comment: @peteb This is a very important side information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing `JSON.parse(schema.toString())` with `JSON.parse(schema.toString().trim())` worked!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the JSON file may have a UTF8 BOM at the beginning. Try converting the file to UTF8 without a BOM.

Comment: You can do that with Notepad:
Open the file.
File > Save As
Encoding: select "UTF-8"
Save